# receive emails in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I know that we can receive emails into rails app using ActionMailer configuration or using griddler/mailman gems. But is that possible to receive unique emails?
Ex: When a user is signed up into the app I create him a unique email address.
When the user sends an email to that unique email address rails app should receive that email.

I used google to find the solution but couldn't get the answer. Please help me(reference links are also much appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

no complete solution, but an idea: you could set up a catch all email address on your mail server that receives all mail sent to your domain.

then, in rails you use the mailman/mail gem to receive mails sent to this catch-all address and process it depending on the `To` header.